# Swift framework access level

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing `my framework` which depends on `other framework`. `My framework` can access all the public types and protocols in `other framework`. But when I include `my framework` in a `project`, the `project` cannot use any public types in `other framework`.

Is it possible to enable `project` to access all publics in `other framework`?

I have two solutions:

1. Use `public typealise T = OtherProject.T`, but there are too many types.
2. Also import `Other framework` in `project`, which need extra dependencies.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in the scenario you are describing, the extra dependencies and the `Other framework` are likely to be needed if `Your framework` is used in a project, so why not import them into projects that use `Your framework`?  Otherwise how would `Your framework` function if its dependencies are missing?  Or maybe I'm missing something?